# jQuery plugin and integrating Google Maps with autocomplete

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I'm building a custom made jquery plugin.

I have a trigger ( which sits on a default google map ), which pops out a sort of a plugin option ( let's call it toolbox ). In this toolbox I have an input which serves as the autocomplete input. Everything works fine so far, the dropdown list appears and I get the marker in the right spot. Now, I'd like the plugin to replace the default map from the html with the one generated by the autocomplete.
Here's the code: http://jsfiddle.net/rcbnG/

**EDIT**: I've updated the jsfiddle code so it looks a bit cleaner: http://jsfiddle.net/rcbnG/1/

**EDIT 2:** ( because I did not make myself understood )
The attached code works fine. The autocomplete ( which is a really important point in this plugin ) and the generated map are good.

What's wrong then?
What I'm actually trying to replace in my html is the Google Map embedded code. I'm trying to replace the default one with a NEW IFRAME code which is displaying the map that I just generated using the autocomplete function of my plugin. Basically I need the coordinates ( longitude & latitude ) so I can generate a new iframe with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery gmap3 plugin has an integrated solution for autocomplete to map
http://gmap3.net/examples/address-lookup.html

Comment: thanks mate. I don't have an issue with the actual autocomplete. My issue is that I don't know how I'm supposed to replace the map that's already in the html ( notice the <iframe> ), with the new one, generated by the toolbox.

Comment: i made this earlier, http://jsfiddle.net/rcbnG/3/ which almost does what Seb appears to be after, but the issue with this attempt is that the cloned map becomes static and non-functional.

Comment: all the fiddels are fine and good....but are a lot to wade through when not sure exactly what the issue is. Post the relevant sections of code that need help with, not a mini app that people don't have time to wade through

Comment: as xec said before, he gave me a solution, but it's not the one I'm looking for per se. Indeed the code on jsfiddle is working, but not as I expect it to work. Basically I'd like the newly generated map to be integrated as an iframe ( as if you'd like to embed a map on your page using maps.google.com ). Makes more sense?

Comment: suggest you make a thread with specific details. What part you know how to do, and what part you need help. You understand the iframe url, so make the connection for people to understand **exactly** what you need

Comment: I've edit again the question. I really hope this time I clarified my self ( sorry for being too vague before )

Comment: simple parse issue... make a new thread with the url values displayed, not just the fiddle to go find the url  READ "how to ask questions" will help you and others